# Dropping Postgres schema inside plpgsql function after RETURN QUERY EXECUTE on a table within that schema

Tags: postgresql

I have a plpgsql function that creates a series of UNLOGGED tables in a schema. The function needs to drop this temporary schema after returning results from one of these tables

```
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM scratch_schema.table'

        EXECUTE 'DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS ' || scratch_schema || ' CASCADE';

        EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
            EXECUTE 'DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS ' || scratch_schema || ' CASCADE';
            RAISE;

        RETURN;
```

However when the function attempts to drop the schema I get the following message:

```
[2021-01-19 15:34:04] [XX000] ERROR: could not open relation with OID 124466
```

From what I can discern, Postgres is dropping the schema before the data is read from table. This doesn't seem like it should be possible, but I was able to confirm that if I remove the `DROP SCHEMA ...` line the function is able to execute and return correctly. Is there any mechanism to ensure the schema is properly dropped only after the results are sent?

Comment: Please provide a complete (minimal) function and your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dropping the tables anyway, I don't see the need for unlogged tables.

Use [`TEMPORARY` tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) instead of `UNLOGGED`. Those are dropped at the end of the session automatically. Or you can create them with `ON COMMIT DROP` to have them dropped at the end of the transaction. Cheaper, too.

Comment: I initially tried to use temporary tables, however I have some performance critical functions that require parallelism and INSERT operations into temporary tables disable parallel execution plans which result in massive performance loss.

Comment: @THX1138: Hmm. Reading *from* a temp table cannot be parallelized. But there is no such restriction for the query behind an `INSERT` into a temp table that I know of.